# Converting a table to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, sqlite

I'm building a quiz app in Python 3. The users are shown a bunch of clues and they have to guess the sports star. My current backend is using SQLite, however I want to have a live database using Firebase and so need to change this to JSON format.

The table currently looks like this:

```
Player Name  Difficulty     Year      Club     Apps (Goals)
player_1     easy       2014 - 2017   club        x (y)
player_1     easy       2017 - 2019   club_2      x (y)
player_2     medium     2019 -        club        x (y)
```

Currently, users select the difficulty. I then run a SQL query that gives me a list of all players with that difficulty. The app then displays to the user the last three columns, which are the clues they need to use to guess the player.

To put in into JSON format, I was thinking it would look something like this

```
{
    "users":
    {
        "player_1_id":
        {
            "name": "player_1",
            "difficulty": "difficulty",
            "year": [year_1, year_2, ..., year_n],
            "club": [club_in_year_1, club_in_year_2, ...., club_in_year_n],
            "apps": [apps_in_year_1, apps_in_year_2, ..., apps_in_year_n]
        },
        "player_2_id":
            "name": "player_2",
            ...
    }
}
```

So there can be different number of values within each list of year/club/apps, per player name. I created and ran the following code:

```
import sqlite3

def dict_factory(cursor, row):
    d = {}
    for idx, col in enumerate(cursor.description):
        d[col[0]] = row[idx]
    return d

connection = sqlite3.connect("player_database.db")
connection.row_factory = dict_factory

cursor = connection.cursor()

cursor.execute("select * from player_history")

results = cursor.fetchall()

print(results)

connection.close()
```

but this prints each new row with a separate ID, which isn't quite what I want.

How would I edit this to get my desired outpout?

Comment: There is not really another way you get it from SQL. You could aggregate the values but you would not get a real array. Otherwise, you have to now take your result rows and change them to your needs. You could use loops and variables to get what you want.

Comment: Aggregate the results yourself, using a per-user keyed dictionary, which itself contains dictionaries and lists depending on how you want to organize the data on a per-user basis. You can then use the `json` library to write out a JSON-formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic solution to map your data.

```py
# define a function that takes a data array as argument
def mapData(data = []):
  # dict that is used to store aggregated rows
  results = {}
  # iterate through the data array
  for item in data:
    # aggreagate values of there is already an entry
    # in the results dict for given name
    if item["name"] in results.keys():
      prev = results[item["name"]]
      prev["year"].append(item["year"])
      prev["club"].append(item["club"])
      prev["apps"].append(item["apps"])
      # continue will skip to next iteration
      continue 
    # create a new entry if there is no existing key
    # for given name in the results dict
    results[item["name"]] = {
      **item,
      "year": [item["year"]],
      "club": [item["club"]],
      "apps": [item["apps"]],
    }
  # return the result
  return results

# some fake data that looks like the data from sql
sqlData= [
  {
    "name": "player_1",
    "difficulty": "difficulty",
    "year":  "2009",
    "club": "2003",
    "apps": "2005",
  },
    {
    "name": "player_1",
    "difficulty": "difficulty",
    "year":  "1999",
    "club": "1998",
    "apps": "2008",
  },
      {
    "name": "player_2",
    "difficulty": "difficulty",
    "year":  "1999",
    "club": "1998",
    "apps": "2008",
  }
]

# pass the data into the function and assign the result
# to a new variable called aggregatedData 
aggregatedData = mapData(sqlData)

# print the result
print(aggregatedData)

# result:      
# {
#    "player_1":{
#       "name":"player_1",
#       "difficulty":"difficulty",
#       "year":[
#          "2009",
#          "1999"
#       ],
#       "club":[
#          "2003",
#          "1998"
#       ],
#       "apps":[
#          "2005",
#          "2008"
#       ]
#    },
#    "player_2":{
#       "name":"player_2",
#       "difficulty":"difficulty",
#       "year":[
#          "1999"
#       ],
#       "club":[
#          "1998"
#       ],
#       "apps":[
#          "2008"
#      ]
#    }
# }
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply! I don't quite understand where the def mapData(data) comes from? Do I have to import a "data" library for this? Do I map it like this before or after calling it from SQLite?

Comment: uhm, maybe time to go back and look at function definition. mapData is a function that takes an argument. I have called it data.Data corresponds to what you pass into the function In my case there, I pass in an array. So data is the array you see on the last line `print(mapData([...]))`  Its the array of rows you get from SQLLte. So you would pass into the function your array that you got form sqlite.

Comment: I took it all apart and added comments so you can understand it more easy. I still would recommend to review the basics.